# How to identify the sound of an "A" without altering the spelling of the word?

Tags: vowels, pronunciation, accent, stress

I have the word "Carr" (short for the name Carrie).

Is there a way to write the 'a' so that a person reading the word 'Carr' would pronounce it like *care* ('kær), opposed to pronouncing it like *car* (kɑr)?

Something like Càrr, Cárr, Cãrr, etc...?

Comment: This question, formulated thus, is tricky to interpret for speakers of certain dialects of English (mine for example); I wouldn't transcribe how I pronounce _care_ as [kær]!

Comment: No. English spelling is not made to represent Modern English vowels, and deviating from standard spellings merely introduces more randomness.

Comment: I think that this might be better in EL&U since it's specifically about English orthography and not IPA or phonology in general.

Comment: I wish there were a solution to this problem, but I don't think there is. I would not recommend using non-English characters: most people would have no idea what you are trying to represent, or you might misrepresent the sound based on usage in another language (eg, á sounds like "aw" in French). But context speaks for itself. If you have a friend Carrie whom you frequently call "('kær)", then she would know what you mean by "Carr". If you are writing a story and refer to a character as "Carr", then you either have to explain the pronunciation some way or accept that it might be mispronounced.

Comment: ...or just spell it "Care'.

Comment: @nxx: That illustrates the problem. For most of the world, *Carrie* is not pronounced like *Care*. So if it is important that the name is pronounced the American way, you need to make it explicit, perhaps having somebody mishear it as *Carey* or *dairy*.

Comment: @nxx, _á_ doesn’t sound like [aw] in French—it doesn’t sound like anything in French, it’s not used at all. _À_ is used, however, and sounds like [ɑ] (as opposed to _a_, which is [a]). Though I doubt you somehow got French and Icelandic mixed up, it is true that _á_ is pronounced [aw] or [ao] or [aʊ] in Icelandic.

Comment: Like musicallinguist, I’d not pronounce _Carr_ (or the first syllable of _carry_) the same as _care_. To me, _Carr_ is /kær/, while _care_ is /kɛr/. The fact that there are so many different mergers and non-mergers in various dialects (and that English orthography is so silly) just makes this distinction impossible to represent accurately without resorting to phonetic transcription.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You are quite right. I meant à, which I guess is more an "ah" than an "aw".

Comment: I took it that the OP was not necessarily suggesting that "Carrie" is pronounced as "Care-y", but that they want the short form "Carr" to be pronounced "care" (for which I take it   [kær] is incorrect anyway), in which case spelling it "Care", making the intended pronunciation explicit, or, ridiculously, "resorting to phonetic transcription", are indeed the only options.

Answer (score 3):

As John Lawler notes in the comments:

> No. English spelling is not made to represent Modern English vowels, and deviating from standard spellings merely introduces more randomness.

The closest you can achieve is to completely alter the spelling to similar to [CoolHandLouis' answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/150239/6006).

Answer (score 0):

Cair could be a spelling actually used for such a name if you don't want the connotation or confusion with the word Care. Also, if fiction, introducing the rhyme "Cair Bear" could help the reader. Also funny enough, "Carrie Berry" rhymes

Comment: "Carrie Berry" only rhymes in (most of) the U.S.

Comment: That's a good point, Peter. They do not rhyme in the UK.

Comment: How about Cair Bear (I'm assuming Cair would be generally considered the same as Care)?  I can modified my answer as needed.  And what is the pronunciation?  Does "Care" rhyme with the first syllable of Carrie?

Comment: "Carrie Berry" only rhymes in (most of) the U.S" <-- Exactly why referring to such (or similar) as rhyming would be a way to establish the pronunciation.

Comment: Care, Kerr, Cair, Kair, Kare.  If that's really what you want.  Kerr has the advantage of being a real name already, and it could be short for Kerry.

Comment: Rhymes don't help with names, Zowie Bowie?  http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-569604.html